# Openshift pod not discoverable, timed out

Tags: java, node.js, networking, openshift

I have three microservices I am deploying in openshift. Service A, B, C. A is a nodejs app, B is a java app and C again a java app. A nd B is exposed to outside world using **routers**. Both A and B uses C for processing data using **C's service URL**.

Trivial depiction below:

```
A - a.com
B - b.com
C - c.default.cluster.local

A -> C
B -> C
```

Now the issue is from A, I am not able to connect to C, but from B I can connect to C. But from C both A and B is reachable.

```
A -> C - No
B -> C - Yes
C -> A - Yes
D -> B - Yes
```

There is following network policies:

```
1. Allow external calls to A
2. Allow external calls to B
3. Allow all pods in cluster's namespace to communicate, denying from other cluster and namespace.
```

Any pointers to above is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, whomever put "-1" please comment why a -1.

Comment: You note that you are using NetworkPolicies, which might be the place we need to look closer. Is C deployed in the `default` namespace? This is important, as `default` typically has [special rules](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#admin-guide-networking-networkpolicy-setting-default). Otherwise, what happens when you add an explicit "allow" rule from A -> C?

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for suggestion and pointers. It was a defined namespace I am using not the default. It turned out the container in the pod was having a proxy set inside while building the image breaking the communication.  Good day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with similar issue as a reference,  it turned out all the deployment,  service and policies in OCP was correct, but the issue was the container deployed in the pod.

While building image, we were using a proxy to install few tools in the image, which was inside the deployed container, breaking the communication to other pods.  We removed the proxy from image after tool installation and it worked.

Taught me to cover or look from different angle for fixing issues.